# VBA .TopPadding and points to inches conversion math issues

Tags: vba, math, ms-word

According to MSDN 1 inch = 72 points.

According to MSDN selection.tables(1).TopPadding returns/accepts points

MS Word only allows users to manually input table margins (not working with cell margins) in inches.

The problem is that when a user inputs 0.02 inches, vba translates this to 1.45 points when it should obviously be 1.44. When I enter 0.01 inches, vba returns .7 when it should be returning .72.

When I attempted to force the return type into double for higher accuracy, .01 inches came back as .699 etc rather then .72 like it's suppose to.

Point being, I need vba to be able to read the user entered value or convert from points to the user entered value; however, it cannot. (points to inches doesn't correctly work either because the point value being returned is not accurate).

**I was hoping one of the VBA gurus on the site could provide some input as to what causes this or provide a way to force the .toppadding to return an accurate number**

```
Dim test As Double
test = Selection.Tables(1).TopPadding
MsgBox test
```

I believe the problem lies in the fact .TopPadding returns values as singles which causes data to be less then accurate.

edit: The math works if you do higher than 100/inch

Comment: It has to be a precision issue or have something to do with binary math, not my strong suit unfortunately, but I can't even force a value of `1.44` using something like `tbl.TopPadding = CSng(1.44)`.

Comment: Yea, the problem is that .toppadding takes and outputs single datatype but the math requires double. Doing inchestopoints(0.02) does the math correctly but when it is applied directly to the padding, and then re-read using vba, it comes back out as 1.45 rather than the 1.44 that goes in. I'm hoping to find a way to get the number as it is entered on the user's side or correctly calculate the number entered.

Comment: Not sure the math does require double-precision. Single should allow 7 significant digits.  This doesn't exceed that. Seems more likely to be a round-off error as a result of floating point or binary maths.

Comment: For what it's worth, `PointsToInches(1.44)` also returns the correct/expected inches measurement of `0.02`.  Although that doesn't solve the problem. :(

Comment: I'm really hoping to avoid creating a list of returned values for under 100/th inch like "if 1.45 then 1.44*50)

Comment: I can understand that it could be a rounding issue. It seems silly Microsoft would make a built in function that rounds like this. I can some-what understand the limitations as far as the size of a pixel a screen can't be cut down so it might round in a way to make the numbers work with pixel counts. Maybe it's just saying 1 pixel = .05 points?

Comment: I just looked, MSDN is saying 1 pixel 0.75 points, 1.45 is not evenly divisible by .75 so unless there is invisible rounding happening 2x this might not be the problem; if however, there is invisible rounding happening 2x, this seems even sillier to me as this would obviously cause issues.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37890/discussion-between-user2733199-and-david-zemens)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a rounding issue, but not a single/double fp one.

This measurement is stored in a whole number of twips (1/20 of a point), so the only possibilities around 1.44pt are 28 (=1.4pt), 29 (=1.45pt) and 30 (=1.5pt). If you look inside the xml for your document, you will probably see XML such as

```
<w:tblCellMar><w:top w:w="29" w:type="dxa"/>
```

"dxa" is "twip" (I don't know why, nor do I know why these measurements are stored as twips but specified in VBA in points).

For each type of measurement in a table, you get different choices as to how to specify the measurement. In some cases you will be able to specify a percentage or an absolute value, but I think in that case you will also be able to specify a PreferredWidthType in VBA. In this case I *think* the only option is to specify an absolute value, but you could try modifying the XML to see if Word rejects a percentage measurement in this case.

It is also possible that Word adjusts the value you provide to take account of other layout factors (e.g. the height of table/cell borders or some such), which might explain the 1.45/1.5 difference, but I suppose I would look for a simpler explanation in the first instance.

Comment: This is amazingly helpful information. Two things quick: Do you know if its possible to edit the xml of the document through vba and can you link me to a reference explaining the information you posted please?

Comment: I'm accepting this answer while adding the comment that XML is editable through VBA with the Open XML sdk.

Comment: The ISO specifications are the best place for Office/Word XML markup (although the example I gave was from theolder non-ISO XML standard). For info about what's going on internally I usually look at Microsoft's Binary .doc standard - e.g. online, the introductory material about Tables is at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd907418(v=office.12).aspx , but (a) it's pretty hard to follow without understanding a bit more about the way the format works, and (b) I generally use the downloadable PDF version.

Comment: re. XML/VBA etc., to manipulate the XML of a Word document, you really need to work outside Word (while the file is closed). Whenever you work through Word (either via VBA+Automation, .NET+Automation or .NET+VSTO, you are working via Word's object model, not directly with the XML. Although it is possible to work with .docx format from VBA (by unzipping the .docx and using MSXML to work with the XML parts inside), the Open XML SDK needs .NET (e.g. VB.NET or C#). You can also use the Packaging API to work with .docx but using the COM version from VBA would be hard. Much easier from .NET.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you meant "around 1.44pt are 28 (=1.4pt), 29 (=1.45pt), and **30** (=1.5pt)".

Comment: @Hall72215: well spotted! now fixed.